# Using SUBSTR is producing a parse error, what is the fix for this?

Tags: sql, substring, substr

I am trying to substring a column but keep getting the following error. I have tried both substring and substr. How do you get around this?

```
Parse error
Expected tokens: <COMMA>, <FROM>
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    T1."FullName",
    SUBSTR (T1."ID ", 1 , 5) AS "InitialID",
    T1. "Age"
FROM
    "Coustomers" T1
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Some databases use `substring()` instead of `substr()`.

Comment: What do you mean "I am not sure of the database". Do you have any reasonable guesses? Can you tell us what letter it starts with?

Comment: it's SQL Server - dbo

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra space in your column name: T1."ID ". I would suggest not using quotes on the column name unless you have to for some reason. Try changing it to this: T1.ID

You also have a space between T1. and "Age".

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.FullName, SUBSTR(T1.ID, 1 , 5) AS InitialID ,T1.Age
FROM Coustomers T1
```

Comment: I have tried remove the quotes as well and still receiving the same error.

Comment: What client program are you using to connect to the dbms and send the query? MySQL Workbench? That may indicate what dbms you are using, which would be helpful to know.

Comment: Also, is the table name really "Coustomers"? Do you have that correctly written in your query?